# Getting Long Data Type

Tags: java

Can you help me how to get the value of input data that the data type is `long`. I am making a queue program that has a `GUI`. I am having error in getting the value of `long`. This is my method.

```
    public Queue(int s) // constructor
    {
    maxSize = s;
    queArray = new long[maxSize];
    front = 0;
    rear = -1;
    nItems = 0;
    }
```

this is my button who will get the value.

```
    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    a.Queue(jTextField2.valueOf(j) = long);
    jTextField2.setText("");
    refresh();
    jLabel2.setText("");

    // TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

or can you just give me a sample program of queue that has a GUI. THANKS. :)

Comment: what error you are getting can you put the stack trace.

Comment: `long` is a keyword in Java, so there's no way that this will work... `a.Queue(jTextField2.valueOf(j) = long);`  Did you mean to have a variable name there, in place of the `long`?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the long data from the `jTextField2` which is an object of [`JTextField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html), then you can do something like this.

```
long j = Long.parseLong(jTextField2.getText()); // get the string data and parse it to long
// use the long value `j` as you want
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to get the value from `jTextField2` and convert into long and insert it into Queue.

```
String value = jTextField2.getText();
long lvalue = Long.parseLong(value);
a.Queue(lvalue);
```

or in one line `a.Queue(Long.parseLong(jTextField2.getText()));`

`Long.parseLong` might throw `RuntimeException`, whihc should be handled.

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
   try{
       a.Queue(Long.parseLong(jTextField2.getText()));
       ...
   }catch(RuntimeException rex){...}
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is a `getValue()` method in the `JTextField` class.

Comment: RJ. the error was removed but how i will get the input? and call the method from the other class so that it will do the method of queue?